# How to hide get request url

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Any one help me how to hide  particular parameter value in url .I'm using jsp,Java struts.
Example:
Actual url:
Http://localhost:8080/getDetail?detailname=Harry&price=200&recaptcha=le3MV
Expected url:
Http://localhost:8080/getDetail?detailname=Harry&price=200

Comment: This is not possible. You could set a non-HTTP-only cookie and send that with the request but a user would still be able to access it

Comment: I added a captch on page but the issue I could to able to see the captcha value in request  passing to Java page for validation purpose

Comment: **Nothing** that you send to the client is secret. The least accessible tactic you have is to obscure/encode/encrypt data that you send.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a form there are two methods,they are post and get method
Using post method will hide the parameter unlike the get method

or

Use session variables instead of the request parameters

Answer (score 0):

Once a page is loaded, you can do some shenanigans to hide it from the URL bar and from the forward/back navigation, but it's still accessible from the browser history itself and will stay if JavaScript is disabled.

```js
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
url.searchParams.delete("recaptcha");
window.history.replaceState({}, "", url.toString());
```

Comment: How to make the changes url to reflect current page